# Adding a class for numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add a class to paragraphs in regular statement:

```js
$("p").each(function(i, elem) {
  typeof elem === "number" ?
    ($("p").addClass("number")) :
    ($("p").addClass("other"))
})
```

```css
.number {
  color: blue;
}

.other {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>abc</p>
<p>123</p>
<p>dynia</p>
<p>semolina</p>
<p>ogór</p>
<p>234</p>
<p>2345</p>
```

But all elements are green (like not-numbers).
If I instead of adding class type console.log(True/False) I obtain correct results.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `elem` is always `object`. You need the text content of `elem`, which you can get using jQuery's [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method. However, the text content is a string, and you can use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if it can be converted to a number:

```js
$("p").each(function(i, elem) {
  var $el = $(elem);
  $el.addClass(isNaN($el.text()) ? 'other' : 'number');
})
```

```css
.number {
  color: blue;
}

.other {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc</p>
<p>123</p>
<p>dynia</p>
<p>semolina</p>
<p>ogór</p>
<p>234</p>
<p>2345</p>
```

Comment: `Number.isNan()` would be even better :)

Comment: I agree. However, I didn't want to confuse the OP, and `Number.isNaN()` is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass(isNaN($(this).text()) ? "number" : "other")
  })
})
```

```css
.number {color: blue} .other {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>abc</p>
<p>123</p>
<p>dynia</p>
<p>semolina</p>
<p>ogór</p>
<p>234</p>
<p>2345</p>
```

With regular Javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach((el) => {
    el.classList += isNaN(el.textContent) ? "other" : "number"
})
```

```css
.number {color: blue} .other {color: green}
```

```html
<p>abc</p>
<p>123</p>
<p>dynia</p>
<p>semolina</p>
<p>ogór</p>
<p>234</p>
<p>2345</p>
```